# All Arrays in ArrayList get overwritten

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

Here I have a loop in a loop to fill level but when it runs through it fills each ArrayList(Integer) the same way, so in the end every row is the exact same. I just can't figure out how this is even possible, when I am filling in every single field one by one.

```
//... level = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();


for(int x = 0; x < currentLevel.getLevelHeight(); x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < currentLevel.getLevelWidth(); y++){
            currentLevel.getLevel().get(x).set(y, Integer.parseInt(allLines.split("\\.")[x].toString().split(";")[y]));
            System.out.print(currentLevel.getLevel().get(x).get(y));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Content of `allLines`?

Comment: show us `getLevel()`and `set(....)`

Comment: is it fine? `currentLevel.getLevel().get(x).get(y)`

Comment: are you sure this code is hit?

Comment: @npinti here it is: "0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;.0;0;1;0;0;0;1;0;.0;0;1;0;0;1;1;0;.0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;.0;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;.0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;"

In the end every field is 0 because the last line is all 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have initialized

```
level = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

badly. There is only one object `ArrayList<Integer>` and it is stored repeatedly to create the List of Lists.

Comment: It was something similar to that. So i guess i could say you more or less solved it -thank you :)

Comment: ofcourse. I made a loop filling the ArrayList with Arrays but the only problem was, that I accidentaly created the Array outside the loop, so I did fill the entire Array with the same Array. I hope you understand without me sharing the code. @laune

Comment: Thanks, understood - but this is exctly what I was trying to say in my answer.